# <form:checkboxes> 'items' must not be null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to display a form with a list of checkboxes in it. There are 2 Java classes to hold the data I need:

```
public class CategoryAndSelection {

    private Category category;
    private boolean selection;

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public boolean getSelection() {
        return selection;
    }

    public void setSelection(boolean selection) {
        this.selection = selection;
    }

    public CategoryAndSelection() {
    }

    public CategoryAndSelection(Category category, boolean selection) {

        super();

        this.category = category;
        this.selection = selection;
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class GroupAndCategoriesAndSelections {

    private Group group;
    private List<CategoryAndSelection> categoriesAndSelections;

    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(Group group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public List<CategoryAndSelection> getCategoriesAndSelections() {
        return categoriesAndSelections;
    }

    public void setCategoriesAndSelections(List<CategoryAndSelection> categoriesAndSelections) {
        this.categoriesAndSelections = categoriesAndSelections;
    }

    public GroupAndCategoriesAndSelections() {
    }

    public GroupAndCategoriesAndSelections(List<Category> categories) {

        this.group = new Group();
        this.categoriesAndSelections = new ArrayList<CategoryAndSelection>();

        for (Category category : categories) {

            CategoryAndSelection categoryAndSelection = new CategoryAndSelection(category, false);
            this.categoriesAndSelections.add(categoryAndSelection);
        }
    }
}
```

In my controller, I make sure to initialise the data and add it to the Model as an attribute:

```
CategoryRepository cr = new CategoryRepository(pm);
List<Category> catList = cr.getAllForProject(project, "title asc");
GroupAndCategoriesAndSelections groupAndCategoriesAndSelections = new GroupAndCategoriesAndSelections(catList);
model.addAttribute("groupAndCategoriesAndSelections", groupAndCategoriesAndSelections);
```

The appropriate bit of the JSP file looks like this:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="groupAndCategoriesAndSelections">
    <%-- ... --%>
    <c:forEach items="${groupAndCategoriesAndSelections.categoriesAndSelections}" varStatus="status" >
        <form:checkbox path="categoriesAndSelections[${status.index}].selection" value="categoriesAndSelections[${status.index}].selection" />
        <br />
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

This works but for some reason this doesn't:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="groupAndCategoriesAndSelections">
    <%-- ... --%>
    <form:checkboxes items="${categoriesAndSelections}" path="selection" />
</form:form>
```

For some reason it produces an `IllegalArgumentException: 'items' must not be null`. Why is that? What don't I understand about this tag?

Comment: Can you post your controller code where you are filling `groupAndCategoriesAndSelections` aswell?

Comment: @JulianL. Done. Why would you need it, though, if the for-each with form:checkbox is working?